# How to use lat/long as features in regression prediction task

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have few features which are actual lat/long values. If I want to predict a regression dependent variable (like trip time in sec). What would you recommend as best approach to tackle the lat/long features?

```
s_lat   e_lng   end_lat start_timestamp intercept
12339877    -73.992462  40.749401   -74.005142  40.740650   1449987484  1
972146  -73.991051  40.760536   -73.991951  40.746670
```

Also since dependent variable is time in sec, which is positive, so maybe transforming it to log scale is better?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to compare distances between locations and predict trip time solely based on that (not accounting for established roads, etc.), you could just find the distance (using the distance formula on the coordinates) between the coordinates and use that as the independent variable. There should be no need for log scales; just use linear regression since the distance formula always yields positive values. Use trip time for the dependent variable, as you said.

(The distance formula being sqrt((lat2 - lat1)^2 + (long2 - long1)^2).)

Comment: That is **not** the correct distance formula.  Latitude and longitude do not preserve angles and distances because a sphere is not topologically homeomorphic to a Euclidean surface.  Please use the Haversine formula for converting latitude and longitude to distances.